# WordPress: Custom Post Type Permalink taking me back to homepage

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I am new to WordPress so apology if my question looks stupid.

I developed the following custom form to post a specific post type `story` from front end. The problem I am having is the permalink which is being auto generated. When I am trying to access the page it takes me back to homepage. I have a custom page `single-story.php` created for my post type which I thought would be accessed automatically but it is not.

```
<?php
/* Post type: story */
add_shortcode('story', 'trip_story_form_builder_shortcode');

function trip_story_form_builder_shortcode(){
    if($_POST['story'] == 'submit' && !empty($_POST['action'])){
        //echo 'Ok';
    }
    if(isset($_POST['txtTitle'])){
        $title = $_POST['txtTitle'];
    } else {
        //echo 'Please add a description';
    } ?>
    <!-- form starts -->
    <form method="post" name="story_form" action="" id="story_form">
        <div class="text-small">
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Story Title <i class="text-red">*</i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtTitle" name="txtTitle" maxlength="75" required />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Story <i class="text-red">*</i>
                    <div class="margin-top-5"></div>
                    <?php
                        $content = '';
                        $editor_id = 'txtStory';
                        $settings = array(
                            'textarea_name'=> 'txtStory',
                            'quicktags' => false,
                            'media_buttons' => true,
                            'teeny' => false,
                            'tinymce' => array(
                                'toolbar1'=> 'bold,italic,underline,bullist,link,unlink,forecolor,undo,redo'
                            )
                        );
                        wp_editor($content, $editor_id, $settings);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-8">
                    Time of visit:
                    <div class="row margin-top-5">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Year<i class="text-red">*</i>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtYear" name="txtYear" maxlength="4" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            Month<i class="text-red">*</i>
                            <select id="cboMonth" name="cboMonth" class="form-control" required>
                                <option value="">-</option>
                                <option value="January">January</option>
                                <option value="February">February</option>
                                <option value="March">March</option>
                                <option value="April">April</option>
                                <option value="May">May</option>
                                <option value="June">June</option>
                                <option value="July">July</option>
                                <option value="August">August</option>
                                <option value="September">September</option>
                                <option value="October">October</option>
                                <option value="November">November</option>
                                <option value="December">December</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="row margin-top-25">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            No. of heads <i class="text-red">*</i>
                            <input id="txtHeads" name="txtHeads" type="number" maxlength="3" class="form-control" required />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Places visited <i class="text-red">*</i>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtPlaces" name="txtPlaces" maxlength="300" required placeholder="Enter name of the places you visited. Separate places by comma(,)" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Category <i class="text-red">*</i>
                    <?php
                    $args = array(
                        'show_option_all'    => '',
                        'show_option_none'   => '',
                        'option_none_value'  => '',
                        'orderby'            => 'ID',
                        'order'              => 'ASC',
                        'show_count'         => 0,
                        'hide_empty'         => 1,
                        'child_of'           => 0,
                        'exclude'            => '',
                        'include'            => '',
                        'echo'               => 1,
                        'selected'           => 0,
                        'hierarchical'       => 0,
                        'name'               => 'cboCategory',
                        'id'                 => 'cboCategory',
                        'class'              => 'form-control',
                        'depth'              => 0,
                        'tab_index'          => 0,
                        'taxonomy'           => 'category',
                        'hide_if_empty'      => true,
                        'value_field'        => 'term_id',
                    );
                    wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    Total Trip cost <i class="text-red">*</i>
                    <input type="number" id="txtCost" name="txtCost" required maxlength="6" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-10">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    Additional information, if any (max. 600 characters)
                    <textarea id="txtInfo" name="txtInfo" rows="5" cols="80" maxlength="600" class="form-control" placeholder="For example, name of hotel you stayed, name and phone numebr of your cab driver etc."></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row margin-top-20">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="hidden" name="story" value="submit" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_story" />
                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_story' ); ?>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Trip Report" class="btn btn-primary text-medium-small">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
<?php
}

function add_trip_story() {
    if($_POST['story']=="submit" && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {
        $title     = $_POST['txtTitle'];
        $description = $_POST['txtStory'];

        //meta data builder
        $visiting_year = $_POST['txtYear'];
        $visiting_month = $_POST['cboMonth'];
        $no_heads = $_POST['txtHeads'];
        $places = $_POST['txtPlaces'];
        $trip_cost = $_POST['txtCost'];
        $addl_info = $_POST['txtInfo'];

        $new_post = array(
            'post_title'    => $title,
            'post_content' => $description,
            'post_type'     =>'story',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        );

        //insert the the post into database by passing $new_post to wp_insert_post
        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);

        //We now use $pid (post id) to help add our post meta data
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visting_year', $visiting_year, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visiting_month', $visiting_month, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visiting_heads', $no_heads, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visiting_places', $places, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visiting_cost', $trip_cost, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, '_visting_addl_info', $addl_info, true);
    }
}

add_action('init','add_trip_story');
```

The above form renders and saves data perfectly in database.

I want to load a single `story` as local.tourplanner.com/story/title-of-the-story. The permalink WordPress is generating is `http://local.tourplanner.com/winter-vacation-at-auli-a-brief-report/` which always takes me to homepage.

But how can I tell WordPress to use a specific pattern for my `story` post type. Is there a way to define it in the above code?

May I ask a couple of more things please?

1. How can I see these posts created bu users inside `wp-admin` as I am not registering this post type using `register_post_type` function?
2. I have a category dropdown in the form. How can I tell WordPress to use this as a sub-link and load posts associated with this category?

I am sorry for putting more than one question in one post. I only wanted to place them at one place because they look to be related.

**UPDATE**
I have discarded the idea of storing data the way I was doing far and created a `custom post type` by registering it with `register_post_type` function.

**Function to render the form:**

```
function render_user_story_form() {

    $form='<form id="user_story_form" name="user_story_form" action="" method="post">';
    $form .= '<div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="_title" name="_title" maxlength="75" required placeholder="Story title" /></div>';
    $form .= '<div><textarea id="_description" name="_description" rows="5" cols="80" class="form-control" maxlength="500" required placeholder="Your story here"></textarea></div>';
    $form .= '<div><input type="text" class="form-control" id="_places_visited" name="_places_visited" maxlength="100" required placeholder="Places visited during the trip" /></div>';
    $form .= '<div><input type="number" class="form-control" id="_trip_cost" name="_trip_cost" maxlength="6" required placeholder="Trip cost" /></div>';
    $form .= '<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" />';
    $form .= '</form>';

    echo $form;
}

add_shortcode('new-user-story', 'render_user_story_form');
```

Below is the code snippet what I have written to store data in `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables but nothing is getting stored.

```
function save_user_story() {
    $title = $_POST['_title'];
    $description = $_POST['_description'];
    $places = $_POST['_places_visited'];
    $cost = $_POST['_trip_cost'];

    $post = array(
        'post_title' => $title,
        'post_content' => $description,
        'post_type' => 'user_story',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
    );

    $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post, 10, 1);

    add_post_meta($new_post_id, '_places_visited', $places);
    add_post_meta($new_post_id, '_trip_cost', $cost);
}

add_action('save_post_user_story', 'save_user_story', 1, 2);
```

Name of my post type is `user_story`.
Reference: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/117269/saving-custom-post-in-custom-form/117331

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Post Type data isn't stored, it's added in runtime from `register_post_type` `args` supplied.

So, as you are using it, WP possibly can't relate the data to custom post type while in front end or back end.

1. If you don't want to use that function, you have to write your own
   `WP_Query` for a similar feature like post type.
2. Also, to create custom backend menu and run those queries on them to
   display data using `WP_List_Table` class.
3. Lastly, URL routing has to be handled separately.

So, if you avaoid `regester_custom_post_type` you got do everything a framework does, other than some front end and DB insert function.

Hope I have clarified your 3 questions on URL, category-URL and backend data.

Comment: As far as storing and retrieving data the form works fine. I am already using `WP_Query` to fetch data for `post_type=>'story'` in my list page. But I don't know how to use a custom rewrite pattern without using the function. Actually I tried to create a form using `meta_box` and by registering post type but I could not figure out well enough as I am still new to WP. If you please send me a tutorial link about this that will greatly help me.

Comment: How can I bring the same custom post type entry form created with `register_custom_post_type` to the front end? Will a `shortcode` do it? If yes, when I save data shall I use `wp_insert_post` and this will put the meta data in `wp_postmeta` table automatically? I googled about this but could not find a proper answer to it. Would you mind explaining this a bit please?

Answer (score 0):

1) The easiest way to set custom post-type permalinks is with the plugin of the same name: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-permalinks/

It will accomplish exactly what you are trying to do with minimum fuss.

2) You should still register your post-type with `register_post_type` in a custom plugin or `functions.php`. This at least creates the table in the DB your front-end form will deposit the content into.

3) You'll have to map the dropdown category used on the front-end form to a DB field that is a part of your custom post type. For custom fields, I love the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. It will support this structure and write correctly into the database, very easy to use at the template layer as well.

I might also suggest you look at the WP-API suite of features. This would allow you a programmatic set of hooks to tap into a custom post-type from the front-end. What you are doing right now is pretty hacky.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have meantime discarded the idea of saving custom post type data the way I was doing. Rather I have now created a custom post type using `register_post_type` function which is coming up in admin. BTW, I am already using ACF in my other two CPTs. Because I am learning WP I wanted to create one of my own. In my new CPT I have created three CM Boxes and could show the form in front end page using a `shortcode`. But here I am lost. Gone through some articles but cannot save the data in `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` tables. Added more information in next comment.

Comment: I have written a function `render_user_story_form` which outputs the form. Then written another function `save_user_story` which is supposed to save the data. Added `add_action('save_post_user_story', 'save_user_story', 1, 2);` to store the data. I must have done thing wrong here. I updated my question with `save_user_story` function. Please advise.